# How should I display dynamic database information?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax, database

I have a script running that updates my database with live scores of sporting events from an external data source. My question to you guys would be, what is the proper way to display this data so that it constantly updates as the database information does? Does it have to be ajax? Is there a simpler option available?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two high-level options:

1. Poll (ajax) the server every X seconds
2. Use an pub/sub-like system (google SocketIO)

Comment: I kind of figured it would have to be ajax. Guess I'll start researching now!

Comment: If you have any examples that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You can find some good examples and explanations in the SocketIO wiki: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I know is to use a timer (`setInterval`) that will check your database periodically. John Resig wrote a post about the javascript timers [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). That is my suggestion, so hopefully, that can be helpful. :)